# Why would an NSURLSession in IOS 9 generate error "NSPOSIXErrorDomain “Operation Cancelled"?

Tags: ios, ios9, nsurlsession

In iOS 9, I'm using NSURLSession and for one specific URL, it's generating the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=89 "Operation canceled".
```

Configuring ATS diagnostic, using nscurl --ats-diagnostics for current url returns a nil error.

Anyone else seen this kind?

**Update:** 
now give response:
  
"curl --head soap.alfabank.kz:30444/soa/rate?wsdl"

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed Content-Type: application/soap+xml; 
charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 286 
Server: Jetty(8.1.14.v20131031) 
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=157680000 
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY
```

Some code:

```
let url = "https://soap.alfabank.kz:30444/soa/rate?wsdl"
let soapMessage = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\"><s:Body xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><GetRates xmlns=\"http://soa.rate.alfabank.kz/\"><RateListRq reqid=\"6f56631b-01d0-4886-917b-1c5565743627\" systemcode=\"VSTest\"><list_type xmlns=\"\">short</list_type><period xmlns=\"\"><fromDate>2016-09-07</fromDate><toDate>2016-09-07</toDate></period></RateListRq></GetRates></s:Body></s:Envelope>"
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:url)!)
let msgLength = soapMessage.characters.count
request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue(String(msgLength), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = soapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
    data, response, error in
       if error != nil {
           print(error)
       }
      else {
//some            
      }
   }
task.resume()
```

Comment: if you use "curl --head" from the command line and give it the problem URL, does it show anything interesting?

Comment: No, nothing shows.

Comment: Nothing?  You mean "curl" gets no response from the server?

Comment: Can you show us the URL?

Comment: @dgatwood  url for connect - [link](https://soap.alfabank.kz:30444/soa/rate?wsdl)

Comment: @PhillipMills Show answer "curl --head"  in qwestions

Comment: Annoyingly, the SOAP standard is fundamentally broken and demands a 405 response for HEAD.  That said, this URL works for me with NSURLSession.    `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://soap.alfabank.kz:30444/soa/rate?wsdl"];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {...}];`

Comment: So basically, please post some of your code so that we know how you're requesting the URL.  And be aware that SOAP URLs reply ONLY to `GET` and `POST` requests (http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part2/#http-bindrespnode).

Comment: @dgatwood Added my code. Thank you for helping me

Comment: You should not be setting the `Content-Length` header yourself.  `NSURLSession` sets that for you based on the actual data length in bytes (which is *not* necessarily the same as the number of characters if you end up with UTF-8 characters in there).  Other than that, the code looks okay.  By any chance is the session itself getting released or invalidated elsewhere in your app?

Comment: @dgatwood
Commented line with "Content-Length" did not help, i try create new application and run this code - the error remains,
Mabye bag in server side?

Comment: I used curl to send what should have been that exact POST request to that URL and it worked fine.  But NSURLSession gives me the same error, and now I'm not able to reach the server.  No idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space after the semicolon in the Content-Type header.  Apparently **NSURLSession** is *very* picky about validating that header (because a curl request succeeded without making that change).

And remove the Content-Length header as previously noted.

Comment: Really?  It worked for me (after those changes) when I converted your code line-by-line to Objective-C and stuck it into an existing app.  Are you doing something interesting in some of your delegate methods?

Comment: Thank you very much, now it work! No idea why yesterday did not work